# Creating Staff Listing

Tags: php, mysql

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something incredibly simple. I want to create a table of my staff members using PHP/MySQL and display in an HTML table. I've gotten as far as writing the query and trying to fetch the array, but it keeps returning a bool variable. Where have I gone wrong?

```
<? $memberQuery = "SELECT * FROM members;";
$memberArray = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($memberQuery) or die("error retrieving members"));

var_dump($memberArray); ?>
```

The `var_dump()` returns `bool(false)`, so I'm a bit lost...

Comment: I'm generally in favour of nesting functions, but I'd be inclined to de-nest `mysql_fetch_array` and `mysql_query` in this case. That'll make debugging each output (expected versus actual, see the docs in each case) much easier.

Comment: Have you ensured you are connected to a database successfully?

Comment: Database connection is successful, I also de-nested the mysql_fetch_array prior to posting this and  got the same results.

Comment: Can you add the code where you connect to the database? The more code you provide, the best we can help you

Comment: If you've changed the code you have, please edit the question to reflect it `:)`

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your code:

```
var_dump($memberArray);
```

instead of

```
var_dump($member array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
 $sqlArray = mysql_query($memberQuery) or die(mysql_error ());
```

it will give some information about your problem.
If there is no error you will be able to visit your array with

```
$memberArray = mysql_fetch_query ($sqlArray);
```

Comment: It isn't throwing any errors...the query is executing fine but is returning a bool instead of an array

Comment: You should try to use mysqli_query() function instead because mysql_query() is deprecated (see the php doc).
mysql_query() returns FALSE if there is a problem, so $sqlArray may be a ressource in other case (mysql_error returns no error).